# jQuery plugin Modernizr is not working after AJAX called page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am loading a page in my website using ajax in WordPress. Page is loading properly, plugin is working in reload a page but when fetching that page through AJAX, plugin is not working. Plugin name is Modernizr custom.

I am calling the plugin in footer simply like this;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/root/webz/js/modernizr.custom.26633.js"></script>
```

I have tried get script but it is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

Modernizr will only work when it is placed in the `<head>`. You cannot load modernizr dynamically via an AJAX call.